# Eclipse Kepler specify appearance theme through command line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

In Eclipse Kepler, each time you start a new workspace, the theme reverts to the default one.

So you need to go to `Windows > Preferences > Appearance > Theme` and select the theme you want to use. After that you need to restart your workspace for the theme to be applied completely.

This is a repetitive and task and time consuming.

Is it possible to specify the theme in the command line or in the `eclipse.ini` file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify

```
org.eclipse.ui/CURRENT_THEME_ID=theme id
```

in the `plugin_customization.ini` file which is in the `plugins/org.eclipse.platform_<version>` directory in the install.

You can also specify the location of the file in the `eclipse.ini`:

```
-pluginCustomization
plugin_customization.ini
```

Comment: I thought your answer would solve my problem, but couldn't get it to work. If I add `org.eclipse.ui/CURRENT_THEME_ID=org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_classic` to my `.ini` file, it does nothing. Exporting preferences and looking at the `.epf` file shows `/instance/org.eclipse.ui/CURRENT_THEME_ID=org.eclipse.ui.defaultTheme`. I know that my `.ini` file is being used, since changing other settings in it has an effect.

Comment: There was a bug in very old versions of Eclipse (around 3.3) where this didn't work, other than that I don't know of any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a new question, referencing back to this one, if I get the time.